# Iterate over non None items in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of strings, some which happen to be None:

```
headers = ['Name', None, 'HW1', 'HW2', None, 'HW4', 'EX1', None, None]
```

Now I would like to iterate over this list, but skip the None entries.  For instance, something like this would be nice:

```
for header in headers if header: print(header)
```

But this doesn't work.  There are two ways I could get this to work, but I don't like either method:

```
for header in (item for item in headers if item): print(header)
```

and

```
for header in headers:
    if header: print(header)
```

I just was curious if there was a better way.  I feel like ignoring None's should be quite fundamental.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
headers = ['Name', None, 'HW1', 'HW2', None, 'HW4', 'EX1', None, None]
for header in filter(None, headers):
    print header
```

Comment: Take care as this is not iterating of things that are not `None`, as the documentation says "If function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are false are removed.". Which is equivalent to `[x for x in headers if x]` which is different from `[x for x in headers if x is not None]`.

What you want here is probably something like: `filter(lambda x: x is not None, headers)`, or even the comprehension.

This may not change much in many cases, but if you deal with numbers, all 0 would be removed. In your case, all empty headers `""` would be removed.

Answer (score 6):

You can get rid of the `None` items with a list comprehension:

```
headers = [item for item in headers if item is not None]
for item in header:
    print item
```

Comment: The only answer here that's correct, by using `is not None`. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
headers = filter(None, headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out the `Nones` with a simple list comprehension:

```
headers = [header for header in headers if header]
```

Then call your code:

```
for header in headers:
    print(header)
```